# How to use wildcard in sql query in golang

Tags: mysql, rest, go, sqlx

```
query := "select p.project_id,p.name,p.org_id,p.user_id,p.email,p.status_ind,p.approver,p.favorite,p.create_timestamp,t.name as tagname,count(b.name) as total,t.colorCode from project p inner join tag t on p.project_id = t.project_id  ";
    q2 := " left join build b on p.project_id = b.project_id AND b.status_ind = \"created\" AND p.status_ind = :status group by p.project_id, t.colorCode "
    //query := "select project.project_id,project.name,project.org_id,project.user_id,project.email,project.status_ind,project.approver,project.favorite,project.create_timestamp,tag.name AS tagname, tag.colorCode from project INNER JOIN tag on project.project_id = tag.project_id where status_ind=:status "
    if q["name"] != "" {
        query = query  + " AND p.name LIKE %:name " 
    }
    query+=q2
    query += " ORDER BY create_timestamp DESC "
    query += " LIMIT :limit;"
```

Here name is parameter which is a golang variable and comes from json request. It is throwing me an error of invalid sql whenever I hit the API.

Comment: LIKE expression should be in single quotes

Comment: still giving same error

Comment: post the executed query here

Comment: if q["name"] != "" {
  query = query  + " AND p.name 'LIKE %:name' " 
 }

Comment: post the ACTUALLY EXECUTED query, the one generated at runtime

Comment: select p.project_id,p.name,p.org_id,p.user_id,p.email,p.status_ind,p.approver,p.favorite,p.create_timestamp,t.name as tagname,count(b.name) as total,t.colorCode from project p inner join tag t on p.project_id = t.project_id   AND p.name 'LIKE %:name'  left join build b on p.project_id = b.project_id AND b.status_ind = "created" AND p.status_ind = :status group by p.project_id, t.colorCode  ORDER BY create_timestamp DESC  LIMIT :limit;

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot for the resource. I have used all permutations and combinations of like. Not able to rectify the error. Sorry if it is a noob question

Comment: select p.project_id,p.name,p.org_id,p.user_id,p.email,p.status_ind,p.approver,p.favorite,p.create_timestamp,t.name as tagname,count(b.name) as total,t.colorCode from project p inner join tag t on p.project_id = t.project_id   where p.name LIKE %:name  left join build b on p.project_id = b.project_id AND b.status_ind = "created" AND p.status_ind = :status group by p.project_id, t.colorCode  ORDER BY create_timestamp DESC  LIMIT :limit; this one doesnt work too

Comment: see if this helps you https://golang.org/doc/database/prepared-statements

Comment: @nbk it's not about prepared statement, he doesn't use LIKE correctly

Comment: yes is see that, but the use of prepared statements is saver

Comment: select p.project_id,p.name,p.org_id,p.user_id,p.email,p.status_ind,p.approver,p.favorite,p.create_timestamp,t.name as tagname,count(b.name) as total,t.colorCode from project p inner join tag t on p.project_id = t.project_id   AND p.name LIKE '%:name'  left join build b on p.project_id = b.project_id AND b.status_ind = "created" AND p.status_ind = :status group by p.project_id, t.colorCode  ORDER BY create_timestamp DESC  LIMIT :limit;   sql: expected 2 arguments, got 3

Comment: @mangusta now the error comes -> expected 2 arguments got 3. I think now it is not picking up :name value

Comment: you shlud check if LIMIT can have a such placeholder at all

Comment: removed limit. same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to keep in mind about SQL syntax:

- The argument to `LIKE` must be a string.
- Parameter placeholders must not be inside SQL string delimiters.

So you need to make the argument to `LIKE` be a concatenated string of `'%'` and the value of your parameter.

There are two ways to do this.

The first way is to use `CONCAT()` to concatenate the literal string `'%'` and your parameter:

```
query := `
  SELECT ...
  FROM project p 
  INNER JOIN tag t ON p.project_id = t.project_id  
  LEFT JOIN build b ON p.project_id = b.project_id 
    AND b.status_ind = 'created' 
    AND p.status_ind = ? 
    AND p.name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?)
  GROUP BY p.project_id, t.colorCode
  ORDER BY create_timestamp DESC
  LIMIT ?`

rows, err := db.Query(query, status, name, limit)
```

The second way is to just use a parameter placeholder, and concatenate the string in Go code before passing it to the query.

```
query := `
  SELECT ...
  FROM project p 
  INNER JOIN tag t ON p.project_id = t.project_id  
  LEFT JOIN build b ON p.project_id = b.project_id 
    AND b.status_ind = 'created' 
    AND p.status_ind = ? 
    AND p.name LIKE ?
  GROUP BY p.project_id, t.colorCode
  ORDER BY create_timestamp DESC
  LIMIT ?`

namePattern := "%" + name

rows, err := db.Query(query, status, namePattern, limit)
```

I show in the example above using Go back-tick strings to make it easier to make multi-line strings that may contain literal quote characters. This is the way I write SQL queries in Go.

As far as I know, MySQL only supports positional query parameter placeholders, not named query parameter placeholders.

Comment: not working still. used second technique

Comment: I can't use the placeholder(`LIKE CONCAT('%', ?)`) in the query without using quotes around it. It throws syntax error